# How to return subnode modified with data from another subnode in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml structure that I want to transform in XSLT 1.0. There is a root node and two subnodes. I want the first node to be output as a result from the transformation and it should be modified with data from the second node.

I have tried applying indentity transform, but I don't know how to get rid of the root node. I can create a copy of the first node, but I can't figure out how to edit it with data from the other one. Here is an example of what I want to achieve. The Member with Id=2 should have nodes merged from the Persons node.

**Input:**

```
<Root>
    <Members>
        <Member>
            <Id>1</Id>
        </Member>
        <Member>
            <Id>2</Id>
        </Member>
    </Members>
    <Persons>
        <Person>
            <Id>2</Id>
            <QAs>
                <QA>
                    <Question>Favourite color</Question>
                    <Answer>Red</Answer>
                </QA>
                <QA>
                    <Question>Best friend</Question>
                    <Answer>Brian</Answer>
                </QA>
            </QAs>
        </Person>
    </Persons>
</Root>
```

**Output:**

```
<Members>
    <Member>
        <Id>1</Id>
    </Member>
    <Member>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <QA>
            <Question>Favourite color</Question>
            <Answer>Red</Answer>
        </QA>
        <QA>
            <Question>Best friend</Question>
            <Answer>Brian</Answer>
        </QA>
    </Member>
</Members>
```

This is what I tried to use as a start, but I can't figure out how to go further:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <!--What to do to get rid of the Root node?-->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Members">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <!--What to do to get data from Persons?-->
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Persons"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross-references are best resolved using a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)**. Try:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="person" match="Person" use="Id" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="Members"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Member">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="* | key('person', Id)/QAs/QA"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks, got me going further. Is there a way to get rid of the root tags, i.e. making Members the root tag?

Comment: I have edited my answer shortly after posting it to fix that. Perhaps you've missed that.

Comment: Yep, missed that. Ok, I see how it works now, thanks.